# Calling drawnow causes heap corruption

Tags: c++, c, matlab, simulink

I'm still new to Matlab and Simulink and I'm seeing a strange problem.

I have a series of Simulink blocks (processA, processB, etc) which are Matlab functions connected serially. They all have the same format.

```
function outConfig = run_processA_Fcn(inConfig)

coder.extrinsic('hilite_system');
hilite_system('myModel/processA');
drawnow;

coder.extrinsic('run_processA_mex');
run_processA_mex(inConfig);

hilite_system('myModel/processA', 'none');
drawnow;

outConfig = inConfig;
```

The function run_processA_mex() is a .mexw64 MEX function which take in pointers to the heap (via inConfig). Inside these MEX functions I am calling my Visual Studio compiled C code (within a DLL).

Each Simulink block could take some time to process, so I wanted it to highlight the current block. The problem is when I call drawnow, the data from my pointers change to some invalid values. The pointers themselves point to the same address, just the values they point to are wrong. If I just comment out the drawnow, my data is okay.

I'm not clear on the best way around this. I don't know why calling drawnow would corrupt my heap. Any help would be great.

Comment: What happens if `drawnow` is defined as `coder.extrinsic`?

Comment: @PhilGoddard Thanks for the comment - I just found out my problem which I've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this was silly of me. The pointers I was passing were pointing to the heap but they were pointers to pointers. The final data was sitting on the stack, so I was losing that data because of the additional function calls I introduced.

I've properly allocated the data onto the heap now and it seems to be working now.